# How to add extra fields to Django Queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'd like to add some extra fields to my queryset.

models.py

```
class Company(models.Model):
    ENTITY_CHOICES  = ( ('CO', 'Corporation'),('PR','Proprietor'),('PA','Partnership'),('NO','Nonprofit'))
    legal_name      = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    entity          = models.CharField(max_length=1, null=True, choices=ENTITY_CHOICES, default='CO')
    client          = models.ForeignKey(Clients, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py

```
qs = Company.objects.filter(entity=PA)
for q in qs:
    q.due_date = '06/15'
for q in qs:
    print('due_date',q.due_date)
```

It was successful in many times. But the result is not stable and I happen to see errors as follows,

```
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'Companies' object has no attribute 'due_date'
```

Is there any better way to add extra attribute to querysets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you iterate through a queryset twice, you are basically querying the database a second time losing your changes in the first loop. You can force evaluate the queryset by using the `list()` keyword, such as

```
qs = list(Company.objects.filter(entity=PA))
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) as

```
class Company(models.Model):
    ENTITY_CHOICES = (('CO', 'Corporation'), ('PR', 'Proprietor'), ('PA', 'Partnership'), ('NO', 'Nonprofit'))
    legal_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    entity = models.CharField(max_length=1, null=True, choices=ENTITY_CHOICES, default='CO')
    client = models.ForeignKey(Clients, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)

    @property
    def due_date(self):
        # your logic for due date
        return due_date
```

**Example:**

```
from datetime import timedelta


class Company(models.Model):
    # your fields
    start_date = models.DateField()

    @property
    def due_date(self):
        # due date is calcualted 10 days from start_date
        return self.start_date + timedelta(days=10)
```

Accessing `due_date`,

```
company_obj = Company.objects.get(id=some_id)
company_obj.due_date  # you will get `due_date`
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually, I need several extra fields and used the same method as you suggest. But, some of extra fields cannot be extracted from models.py itself because they need more complicated logics in views.py. Interested thing for me is that when I try this coding in shell mode. it works!

Comment: You have to either add fields to model and populate those data with appropriate logic or you have to write methods/property to the models in order to *add extra fields to the Django QuerySets*

Answer (score 2):

you must add some field in model.

when in your code add some attribute to model instance like :

```
q.due_date = '06/16'
```

this attribute added to instance and no where stored. so when you fetch instance from database instance has not field/attribute named due_date